# Encrypt/decrypt in java and node.js

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a file in java and the file will be decrypt/encrypt in node.js on the other side.

i generated keystore file using following command

keytool -genseckey -keystore  -storetype jceks -storepass  -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -alias  -keypass

I then encoded the key in base64 format and sent to other party.

in my java code, i dont use base64 form of key. I simply load the key fromthe keystore, initialize my cipher and encrypt the file.

i then sent the encrypt file to other party.

however they are not able to decrypt it. similarly if they encrypt it and i try to decrypt it, i get BadPaddingException. What is going on. is it because they using base64 encoded key and I am not ? rest of all the things are same in terms of algorithm, mode of operation.

Here is decryptfunction I am using:

```
public void decryptFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        long totalread = 0L;
        int nread = 0;
        byte[] inbuf = new byte[128];


        mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        mInitVec = new byte[16];

        inputStream.read(mInitVec);
        mDecipher.init(2, loadKey(), new IvParameterSpec(mInitVec));


        CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, mDecipher);

        while ((nread = cin.read(inbuf)) > 0) {
            totalread += nread;


            byte[] trimbuf = new byte[nread];

            for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) {
                trimbuf[i] = inbuf[i];
            }


            outputStream.write(trimbuf);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}


And here is the loadKey()

try
    {
      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
      FileInputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
      keystore.load(keystoreStream, storePassword.toCharArray());
      if (!keystore.containsAlias(keyAlias)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Alias for key not found");
      }

      KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPassword.toCharArray());

      KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)keystore.getEntry(keyAlias, protParam);
      SecretKey mySecretKey = skEntry.getSecretKey();
      byte[] enc = new byte['Ā'];
      enc = mySecretKey.getEncoded();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new Exception("Error reading key from keystore. Please check if the keystore '" + keyFile + "' exists and is valid."); }
    SecretKey mySecretKey;
    FileInputStream keystoreStream; KeyStore keystore; return mySecretKey;
  }
```

The other party is using node.js the code is

```
//String to encrypt 
var plaintext = data.Body; 
//initialisation vector 
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); 
//cipher based on provided key and iv 
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv); 
//encrypt the plaintext using aes-256-cbc 
var encrypted = cipher.update(plaintext); 
var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]); 
//Need to retain IV for decryption, so this can be prepended to the output 
var encryptedbuffer = Buffer.concat([iv, finalBuffer]); 
var encryptedstring = iv.toString() + finalBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be wrong. Just one is enough that you cannot decrypt. Without more details (code of both sides) we cannot help.

Comment: You must use the same key with the same encoding, incorrect decryption will usually generate a padding error. There may also be a difference between the implementations. Add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: Added code for both sides

Comment: Hmm, that's two times the encryption code. I was hoping to see one encryption and the decryption of the other side.

Comment: decrypt code is same except cipher is initialized for decyrption. as of now if i encrypt with my java code they are not able to decyrpt it.if they decrypt it with node.js , i am getting BadPaddingException. As you can the algorithm used are same.

Comment: If it's really the same, they are generating a random IV instead of using your's that was used for encryption.

Comment: Uhhhhh... Well there's a 1 in 2^16 chance of getting the right IV in your Node js code so your odds aren't looking too good at the moment.  Crypto is hard, hire someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: @LukePark chances are much worse: 1 : 256^16

Comment: @Henry Oh yeah 16 bytes, not bits...  Point proven!

Comment: I have updated the code. now i show encrypt and decrypt.